# Picture on the same location, when resizing of browser page

Tags: html, css, web

[Half page browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFDuC.png) 
[Full page browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EIuA.jpg)

Hi, need you guys to help on my program. How do I place my robot on the same location as my "Half page browser" when I do a full screen browser. When I open to a full-screen browser, the location of the robot moved.

Please guide me on it.

Below will be my coding for the web-page:

```
    <html>
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title></title>
         <style>

              body {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                background-image: url('TPHRG floorplan1.png');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size:   contain;

                }

            </style>

              <body>

                <img id="robot" style="position: fixed;  top:200px; left:450px; border-radius: 50%; width:50px; height:60px" src="pic_8.PNG">

                <?php



                 ?>

              </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Don't use fixed pixels, use relative units like %.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it like this.

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: contain;
```

Remove above CSS and add below

```
background-size: cover;
```

Hope this will help you.

PS: check it in **full page** mode

```css
#robot {
  position: fixed;
  top: 200px;
  left: 450px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1320x500.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>

  <body>
    <img id="robot" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png">
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The position of robot image should be Percent.

For ex:

```
#robot{top:20%;left:30%}
```